# why does it say this: "TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, vgg-net, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make a custom vgg-like model, with dropout and swish activation function. I completely do not understand what the problem is here. I am beginner, so maybe I am entirely wrong. I would not think so though, since I go by example of the tutorials and guides.

Here the code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten, Activation
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

def swish(x):
    return K.sigmoid(x) * x

custom_vgg = Sequential()
img_width = 224
img_height = 224
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
print(vgg_model.get_config())
#vgg_model.save_weights('models/vgg_weights.h5')
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    if layer.__class__.__name__=='MaxPooling2D':
        layer.trainable = False
        custom_vgg.add(layer(activation = swish))
        custom_vgg.add(Dropout(0.4))
    else :
        custom_vgg.add(layer)
custom_vgg.add(Flatten())
custom_vgg.add(Dense(1024,activation=swish))
custom_vgg.add(Dense(1024,activation=swish))
custom_vgg.add(Dense(128, activation = "softmax"))

custom_vgg.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])

custom_vgg.summary()
```

console saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shavkatsultanov/Documents/SCHUETZ/tensor_flow/vgg_swish.py", line 20, in <module>
    custom_vgg.add(layer(activation = swish))
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

I am wondering, because I tried similar things, the iterating over layers and adding to another model, and it had worked. Also when it is in line 20, it should not be expecting any 'inputs' or whatever?

if someone could help here, that'd be great, thanks!

edit: I am wondering if the thing with the if-statement, asking about the class_name, if that maybe is wrong somehow? really hope someone can solve this

Comment: I think you want to define a new layer type, with its own activation function, like in here: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> custom_vgg.add(layer(activation = swish))
> ```

You're calling a `layer` *object* (this is not creating a layer, it's calling a layer you got from an existing model). And apparently keras layers are callable, `layer(...)` being a wrapper around a bunch of internal logic (that's... not a very good API I think).

Either way, just... don't call the layer.

Comment: `for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    if layer.__class__.__name__=='MaxPooling2D':
        layer.trainable = False
        layer.activation = swish
        custom_vgg.add(layer)
        custom_vgg.add(Dropout(0.4))
    else :
        custom_vgg.add(layer)`

Comment: hey, which API do u use, if I may ask?